# How do I implement an onClickListener for a CardFragment in Android Wear?

Tags: java, android

How do I implement an onClickListener for a CardFragment in Android Wear? There seems to be no methods such as setOnClickListener in either the CardFragment or the GridPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way to do it but I created a new Fragment who implements `View.OnTouchListener` :

```
public class ActionFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnTouchListener {

    (...)

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // PRESSED
                circledImageView.setCircleColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_button_pressed));
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // RELEASED
                Log.i(TAG, "Action!");
                return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```